# how to handle input redirection

Tags: c++, linux, input, user-input

I have a simple menu, something like the following:

```
while(cmd != quit){
    cin >> cmd;
    swith(cmd){
        case 'a':
            blah();
            break;
        case 'b':
            boo();
            break;
     }
}
```

what would i have to do inorder to make sure it handles not only input from the console, but also file redirection in unix/linux?

thanks!

Comment: Nothing *more* to do. What you have already works with file redirection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean redirection as in:

```
echo 'a' | ./your_program
```

In that case you don't have to do anything special. The shell already directs your input into stdin of your program.

Comment: ERM, well, not exactly. You see, there's the issue of escape sequences...Not sure if C++ stream I/O cleaned it up, but it can be a mess in pure C...

Answer (score 0):

There is fflush series of functions in C and C++. Think this can be of use when there is some issue with the streams.